# What determines whether the spin and orbital angular momentum are coupled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We were just introduced the the total angular momentum quantum number $j$ and then shown the spin orbit interaction. The splitting of energy levels was derived in the reference frame of a stationary electron. I can't seem to find a criterion for what determines whether the spin and angular momentum couple or not. Are these energy levels just always split?

Comment: In principle they always couple. Only if we like to obtain a simple model we omit the coupling.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks